# how to identify the reason for Tika processor not working for OCR documents(Scanned PDF Documents) in my system?

Tags: pdf, apache-tika

Tika Procesor works fine for normal unscanned PDF files but  could not process the Scanned PDF documents , eventhough I have installed  Tesseract and the following dependencies in my Mac.
My java version- "1.8.0_112", tesseract 3.04.01, leptonica-1.74.1, libjpeg 8d : libpng 1.6.28 : libtiff 4.0.7 : zlib 1.2.8.

but the same code with the above mentioned depedencies in my friends Mac works perfectly for scanned PDF doucuments.

how to identify the reason for not Tika processor working in my system as  the same code with same dependencies works fine in other systems?
pom.xml has :

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
      <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
       <artifactId>tika-parsers</artifactId>
       <version>1.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
       <artifactId>jai-imageio-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
       <groupId>com.github.jai-imageio</groupId>
       <artifactId>jai-imageio-jpeg2000</artifactId>
       <version>1.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.levigo.jbig2</groupId>
      <artifactId>levigo-jbig2-imageio</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
     <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
     <version>1.59</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcmail-jdk15on</artifactId>
      <version>1.59</version>
   </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
     <artifactId>bcpkix-jdk15on</artifactId>
     <version>1.59</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: Try following the [Apache Tika troubleshooting guide?](https://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika)

Comment: Have you configured Tika to extract inline images from PDFs or to render pages and then run ocr? See the OCR section: https://wiki.apache.org/tika/PDFParser%20%28Apache%20PDFBox%29